# How to mock StorageOptions.newBuilder()

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, junit, mockito, google-cloud-storage

Can you help me in mocking StorageOptions.newBuilder()

Code to be Mocked:

```
StorageOptions.newBuilder.setProjectId("Test").build().getService()
```

Code I have written:

```
Storage mockStorage = Mockito.mock(Storage.class);

MockedStatic<StorageOptions> storageOptionsMock = Mockito.mockStorage(StorageOptions.class);
storageOptionsMock.when( ()-> StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId("Test").build().getService()).thenReturn(mockStorage);
```

Error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Storage$MockitoMock$1939527098 cannot be returned by newBuilder()
newBuilder() should return Builder
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are chaining a lot of method calls, you can use `Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` to instruct Mockito to return all the required intermediate stubs/mocks.

```java
Storage mockStorage = Mockito.mock(Storage.class);
MockedStatic<StorageOptions> storageOptionsMock = 
    Mockito.mockStatic(StorageOptions.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

storageOptionsMock.when(()->  
    StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                  .setProjectId("Test")
                  .build()
                  .getService())
.thenReturn(mockStorage);

assertThat(StorageOptions.newBuilder()
    .setProjectId("Test")
    .build()
    .getService())
.isEqualTo(mockStorage);
```

But since this is considered an [anti pattern](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS), you may want to refactor your code to avoid this.

Comment: Thank you. It worked.